# Postfix: How (and why) set up /etc/aliases.db?

Tags: postfix

I have postfix set up and a local user `myuser`.

An email to `myuser@mydomain.com` is arriving without problems, so the basic postfix setup is fine.

I have then set up virtual alias:

```
mylongname@mydomain.com    myuser@mydomain.com
```

and in main.cf:

```
mydestination: mydomain, localdomain
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/path_to_virtual_aliases
```

I also created the database with `postmap /path_to_virtual_aliases`

When I send an email to `mylongname@mydomain.com`, I get this error:

```
postfix/local[2341]: error: open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory
postfix/local[2341]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
postfix/local[2341]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases is unavailable. open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory
postfix/local[2341]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases: lookup of 'myuser' failed
postfix/local[2340]: F1D9C233E9A: to=<myuser@localdomain>, orig_to=<mylongname@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=2239, delays=2239/0.03/0/0.02, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (alias database unavailable)
```

Why does it try to look up myuser, when it is already a native user?

And if it really has to look it up, will the problem be fixed by setting up /etc/aliases? And if yes, how to do so?

Comment: Does your system have a `newaliases` command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are mixing up two forms of aliasing which are used at different stages of delivery.

- [virtual_alias_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps) are a feature of postfix which let it completely re-route an email.  They are used at a stage *before* postfix has decided what to do with an email and thus can be used to re-route specific email to a completely different email server.
- [alias_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_maps) are a feature of posftix's local delivery which allow one *local* mail box to be aliased as another *local* mail box.  They are used at a stage after postfix has decided to deliver the email locally and so cannot be used to re-route to another server.  [See here](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html):

  > DESCRIPTION:
  > The  aliases(5) table provides a system-wide mechanism to redirect mail
  > for local recipients. The redirections are  processed  by  the  Postfix
  > local(8) delivery agent.

---

> Why does it try to look up myuser, when it is already a native user?

This is applied to all local users and can be very useful where you are receiving mail that isn't covered by [virtual_alias_domains](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains).  For example redirecting email for many system services into one mail box.

---

> And if it really has to look it up, will the problem be fixed by setting up /etc/aliases? And if yes, how to do so?

Yes, just create an empty `/etc/aliases` then populate `/etc/aliases.db` file with [postalias](https://linux.die.net/man/1/postalias):

```
postalias /etc/aliases
```